# Permission Denied in VS Code Terminal & Mac Terminal (Continuation of First Question)

Tags: c, terminal, cs50, permission-denied

***For Context on the update, please read the comments from my first question. I'll post the details for my first post below***

For Stark's comment, I typed what the instructor told me which I'll insert below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)


{
    printf("Hello, welcome to the world of code!/n");
}
```

I assume that to compile c, it was the `#include <stdio.h>`that would make this work. If I am wrong or misunderstood please let me know. I read the tutorial that TSG posted and it looks similar to what I put. So I'm unsure of what I did wrong. Also to answer stark, I wanted it to print out the statement *Hello, welcome to the world of code!* just to make sure that it would actually work if I tried it out myself. Any additional thoughts?

**From Previous Post**
I am currently learning about coding through CS50 because it has piqued my interest. However, I am having a big problem. No matter what I do, anytime I type in my terminal `./[nameofdocument]` , I always get the response "`permission denied`". I've tried uninstalling the shell path & reinstalling it, doing the `sudo chown -R` thing, looking at the file which it says I can read & write on it, and updated my shell from using bash to zshell. However, it doesn't matter what shell I use or even if my computer says that the folders & file have full access, I just have no way of accessing it (or I think the terminology is running it). I genuinely don't know what to do and I'm not sure if it's because I don't know what I'm doing but I feel defeated trying to just do a basic task and I constantly get the response that my permission is denied. If this is of any importance, I'm using the language C and I've downloaded all the extensions from Microsoft only. I also am using my MacBook Pro that is on *macOS Monterey version 12.6*. If anyone can help me or is willing to do a 1v1 call or would like to guide me on what to do personally (with this issue and in general) please let me know. I do not want to let this deter me from using VS Code and I really would like to learn to be a software engineer.

Comment: There are interpreted languages that just run the file that you type.  C is not one of them.  The C compiler is a separate program that converts your source file to an executable file that you can run.  gcc is a C compiler.  A comment in the previous post explained what you need to do.

Comment: Change `/n` into `\n` to output a newline. If your program source is in `xyz.c`, compile with `cc -o xyz xyz.c`. Then do: `./xyz` Nothing more needs to be done to execute the program. Note that all your attempts at remedying the problem (e.g. `chown`) may have done more harm than good, so caveat emptor.

Comment: After looking at your prior question, I'm inferring that `./[nameofdocument]` pertains to the _source_ file. Normally, that has a `.c` extension. Relative to my previous comment, you probably did something like: `./xyz.c`. That is, you tried to execute/run the _source_ file and _not_ the _executable_ program (which you get by compiling the source).

Comment: I get it now. I'm still trying to understand the terminology so I didn't understand what g++ meant and didn't understand that what I put was the source file instead of the executable program. Thank you both for your help and patience :)